# Can the list of targets for "does not belong here" be expanded?

Tags: feature-request, migration

The current list **belongs on...** only contains Meta UL.

I request to expand this list to

- Server Fault
- Superuser
- Stack Overflow
- IT Security

In descending priority.

Comment: AskUbuntu would fit in nicely too.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx I did not see that many Ubuntu-questions here (see statistics from Michael in his answer). I saw more Ubuntu-questions on SF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm all for it, but generally sites only get migration paths if they demonstrate a need for them. In the last 90 days we've sent 1 post to SF, 3 to SU, 20 to SO, and 2 to ITSec, which is probably way too low to add any of them to the list

Comment: Interesting numbers. I would have thought there were more migrations. Perhaps the numbers are low, because there is no path yet? Any way - it would make your live easier...