# Can we have Super User as a site for off-topic close reasons?

Tags: feature-request, migration, close-reasons

I'm looking at [Mac equivalent application "shortcat"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81860/mac-equivalent-application-shortcat). While it technically relates to Unix & Linux, I think it would be a much better fit for Super User.

However, I was only able to flag as belonging on Meta U&L, or Stack Overflow. Can we add Super User to that list?

**Edit:** as pointed out by jasonwryan, there's [Can the list of targets for "does not belong here" be expanded?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/971/can-the-list-of-targets-for-does-not-belong-here-be-expanded).

Still, that was 2012, almost exactly a year ago. I'd be interested to take a look at the numbers again.

Comment: See http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/971/can-the-list-of-targets-for-does-not-belong-here-be-expanded

Comment: I have no problem with the question in question. Especially considering all operating systems in question are Unix

Comment: @xenoterracide yeah, I was intending to flag because I think it'd fit Super User much better, and I thought it would get better answers there. I'd agree that it is technically OK on U&L, though.

Comment: the author can always request we do it, and we will. So if you convince the author to ask us to migrate...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's incredibly rare that we get a question that's on-topic for SU and actually off-topic here; as you mentioned, even your example question is actually on-topic here, it's just possibly better on SU. In any case, the numbers haven't changed; we migrated 3 posts to SU in the last 90 days, which is pretty low for a migration path

Comment: how'd you get those stats btw... I was poking the mod tools, but couldn't find an obvious way

Comment: @xenoterracide http://unix.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/migrated/stats