# Can we have Server Fault (or other SE site) as an off-topic choice?

Tags: discussion, support

From time to time we'll get a question that seems more on-topic for Server Fault rather than Unix & Linux.  Such as this one, "[Xen HW virtualization on Power architecture?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91368/xen-hw-virtualization-on-power-architecture)".

However when going through the "close as off-topic" picks I've never been able to find a way to off-topic something other than to Stack Overflow?

#### Questions

1. Is it possible to pick Server Fault?
2. If not can it be added, or was it not for some reason not obvious to me?
3. If it's possible what's the trick?

I did find this question that @Sturgee as regarding Super User, titled: [Can we have Super User as a site for off-topic close reasons?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1327/can-we-have-super-user-as-a-site-for-off-topic-close-reasons), and I understand the answer to that question, however it never really addressed Server Fault or any of the other SE sites such as Ask Ubuntu either.

#### UPDATE #1

**Answer**: if you absolutely positively think an answer should be migrated, flag the mods via "other" and mention it in the comments that you think it should be migrated to SF. Use cautiously however given the overlap between the various SE sites.

Comment: +1, I would also suggest adding [su] as well.

Comment: @terdon - I've expanded the answer a bit, including AU and/or other SE sites into the mix, also I referenced the one Q I found on meta regarding SU. See the mod's answer regarding the logic behind why that site isn't in the mix. Not sure I agree but I get what he's saying.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is the "from time to time" part. The answer is the same as for the SU question you linked to: they'll only give us a migration path to a site if we're frequently needing to send them posts, and in the last three months we've migrated to SF...twice. SU is up to 5, and AU is up to 8

Server Fault also has unusually restrictive criteria for what posts they consider on-topic, which most people won't know; they'll see "server" in the question and think "sounds perfect for Server Fault, those guys love servers". I don't think they would want the question you linked to, it's not about a professional sysadmin dealing with server administration, it's just a generic question about a CPU that might be in a server

Super User and Ask Ubuntu are even riskier, because their scopes heavily overlap with ours. People are constantly trying to get us to punt questions to AU that are perfectly on-topic here; we only migrate there if the question [doesn't apply to other distros](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (or the asker wants us to), not because they happen to be on Ubuntu

If we start getting a flood of posts that need to be migrated, I'll try to talk SE into giving us new migration paths. Mods can migrate to any site, so for now you can just mod flag posts that need to be moved and we'll deal with it

Comment: Understood, thanks for the quick & thorough response!