# Why can we not vote to migrate a question to superuser.com?

Tags: discussion, review, migration

When we vote to close as off topic, we can select one of a couple of sites to forward the question to such as stackoverflow.com

I'm surprised that superuser.com isn't listed as an option.  Is there a reason for this?

I mentioning because it seems that a pretty good proportion of questions to be closed as off topic would belong there.

Comment: Linking in https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/972/117549 and https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2927/117549 and https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5435/117549

Comment: Thanks for those links.  I feel like [this diagram](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2936/20140) illustrates cleanly why I make the suggestion.  That is SU feels like a super-set of UL with a few script questions falling outside of SU.

Comment: There are a lot of script questions here :)

Comment: Fair enough ;-) I'm personally uncertain why they aren't better on SO. But hey, not going to argue it.

Comment: SO has twice as many [AIX](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/aix)-tagged questions [as we do](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aix) and 6 times as many [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux)-tagged questions [as we do](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux). A "programming"-related Linux script question would be in-scope on SO.

Answer (score 6):

Standing on the shoulders of giants, I'll mention: [When flagging a question to be migrated, why are some Stack Exchange sites excluded?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5435/117549) (with its link to some good reading at [What is the reasoning behind restricting the number of migration paths?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203318/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-restricting-the-number-of-migration-paths)). Shog9's answer on Meta.SE regarding close-vote migration paths raises concerns over whether the OP has (or even wants) an account on the target site and whether the OP -- and the 5 close-voters here! -- are familiar with the target site's scope.

The previous Meta answers here refer to demonstrating a need. Looking at the [migrated stats link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) (via Gilles' answer at [Yearly Revisit of List of Sites to Migrate](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3274/117549)), in the past 90 days, we've migrated *away*:

- stackoverflow.com × 16 (6% rejected)
- superuser.com × 2
- unix.meta.stackexchange.com × 1 (100% rejected)
- android.stackexchange.com × 1
- apple.stackexchange.com × 1

Which doesn't (to me) look like a substantially different ratio than previously, so if history is any indicator, SE staff would not support adding a close-vote migration path to SuperUser.

Comment: Not wishing to seem argumentative but how are stats compiled for sites where we don't have migration paths?  I only ask because I wonder if we correctly we capture closed yet non migrated questions. 2 Seems very low.  I feel like in the past 90 days I've personally voted close on more than that with a polite suggestion to each OP.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where those numbers come from, to be honest. Looking at the [migrated away stats](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away) there are five recent migrations to SU: 2 last December, 1 last August, 1 last July, and 1 last June. Closed-but-not-migrated questions would simply be "closed", right? If it's closed here and separately re-asked, I'm not sure that's captured by any (simple) stats.

Comment: Close-voters needing to be familiar w/ target site would already be a problem with the existing targets. (Possible fix: let me vote to migrate anywhere I have vote-to-close rights on, because that's the best proof we can have.)